# Numpy advanced indexing, bool vs. int IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, boolean

Trying to use numpy advanced indexing into a matrix - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

This works as expected, returning the whole matrix, v

```
import numpy as np
v = np.reshape(np.arange(0,9), (3,3))
v[np.asarray([0,1,2])[:,np.newaxis], np.asarray([0,1,2])]
```

Using logical indexing also works as expected:

```
v[np.asarray([0,1,2])[:,np.newaxis], np.asarray([True, True, True])]
```

Surprisingly (to me, at least), this errors when switching the order of the index vectors?

```
v[np.asarray([True, True, True])[:,np.newaxis], np.asarray([0,1,2])]
```

Or if both vectors are boolean

```
v[np.asarray([True, True, True])[:,np.newaxis], np.asarray([True, True, True])]
```

With the error "*** IndexError: too many indices for array".  I expected the 3rd and 4th examples to work just like the 1st and 2nd.  What am I missing?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing - the last part of this boolean indexing section says you need to use `np.ix_` to generate the relevant indices.  It converts the boolean in to equivalent `nonzero` indices.  Broadcasting does not work with boolean arrays.

Comment: What's the context for this, what are you trying to extract from the array and where do the indexes come from?

Comment: @hpaulj  You are correct.  broadcasting just doesn't work for advanced indexing with boolean arrays.  I was confused because it LOOKS like it works in example 2.  If you make an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

the last part of this boolean indexing section says you need to use np.ix_ to generate the relevant indices. It converts the boolean in to equivalent nonzero indices. Broadcasting does not work with boolean arrays

```
In [48]: np.ix_(np.asarray([True, True, True]), np.asarray([0,1,2]))            
Out[48]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [2]]), array([[0, 1, 2]]))
```

`ix_` generates the correct array indices to perform the block indexing:

```
In [50]: v[np.ix_(np.asarray([True, True, True]), np.asarray([0,1,2]))]         
Out[50]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

The same arrays without `ix` select the diagonal:

```
In [51]: v[np.asarray([True, True, True]), np.asarray([0,1,2])]                 
Out[51]: array([0, 4, 8])
```

Assuming boolean indexing is done with some form of `np.where/nonzero`, it's possible that this 2d `nonzero` result is giving the indexing error.  But it's occurring in compiled code so it's hard to trace the details:

```
In [53]: np.asarray([True, True, True])[:,np.newaxis].nonzero()                 
Out[53]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 0, 0]))
```

We can index with a boolean that matches `v` in shape, but the result is 1d:

```
In [66]: np.array([True,True,True])[:,None].repeat(3,1)                         
Out[66]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
In [67]: v[_]                                                                   
Out[67]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```